# I want to know if it is alright to create a shallow copy of a state that contains an array with objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, state, shallow-copy

Let's say I have this as a state in react  :

```js
const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);
```

1. The cars array contains this :

   ```js
   [{id: 0, brand: 'BMW'}, {id: 1, brand: 'Audi'}];
   ```
2. And I create a copy of this state :

   ```js
   const carsCopy = [...cars];
   ```
3. Now let's say I want to modify the brand property from the last object in the copied array:

   ```js
   carsCopy[1].brand = 'Toyota';
   ```
4. Now the thing is that doing so I mutated the original object that sits in the cars array because in the copy it points to the same objects in the memory;
5. Is this ok or is a bad practice and should be avoided? Should I make a deep copy instead?

Comment: Yes, this is a bad practice. Avoid mutating the shared object. You don't need to make a deep copy though, it's enough to copy the array and the particular car object that you want to update.

Comment: @Phil thanks, I should have known there is a good canonical question

Comment: [`.with()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/with) is a good use case for this (just make sure you copy the object you're setting)

Comment: @NickParsons awesome link but needs the proviso that it requires Node.js 20

Comment: Thanks @Phil - Yeah, its quite new at this stage. It should become more accessible as time moves on though (I imagine there are simple polyfills for it also :))